# Padding and Link Issue in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, padding

I am new to HTML and CSS. I have a row of social media icons that link to their respective pages. The HTML for that:

```
<div id="social">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">
            <img title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" src="img/social/facebook.png" />
        </a>

        <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/">
            <img title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" src="img/social/twitter.png" />
        </a>

        <a target="_blank" href="https://instagram.com/">
            <img title="Instagram" alt="Instagram" src="img/social/instagram.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
#social {
    text-align: center;
}

#social img {
    width: 6%;
    height: 6%;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

The problem is that the 20px of right padding is apart of the link, which is sloppy. How do I create space between the icons without that space being linked? Cheers.

Comment: Active on the comments today @Paulie_D! 8o

Comment: Quick on the answesr today for you too!   If I wasn't spending all my time voting to close a load of poor questions **I'd** be 20k by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set a margin on the `a` elements (except the last one, where a margin would be both redundant, and potentially layout impacting):

```
#social {
    text-align: center;
}

#social img {
    width: 6%;
    height: 6%;
}
#social a:not(:last-of-type){
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide margin between the anchors

```
#social a {
  width: 6%;
  height: 6%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `margin`

```css
#social {
    text-align: center;
    
}

#social img {
    width: 6%;
    height: 6%;
    /*padding-right: 20px;*/
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="social">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">
            <img title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" src="img/social/facebook.png" />
        </a>

        <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/">
            <img title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" src="img/social/twitter.png" />
        </a>

        <a target="_blank" href="https://instagram.com/">
            <img title="Instagram" alt="Instagram" src="img/social/instagram.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of targeting `#social img` in the css, try using `#social a` and `margin-right: 20px` instead of `padding-right`.